# Decide execution method by Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, aop

I need write a code where the method execution will depends of your anotattion. Example:

```
public class Example {
    private final Integer LAYOUT = 1;
    public static void main(String... args){
        executeMethod1();
        executeMethod2();
    }

    @Execute(type = LAYOUT, needs = 1)
    executeMethod1(){
        System.out.println("Layout version 1");
    }

    @Execute(type = LAYOUT, needs = 2)
    executeMethod1(){
        System.out.println("Layout version 2");
    }
}
```

And the result must be:

```
console: Layout version 1
```

Maybe using AOP?

Comment: Use tags for language/library next time.

Comment: This is easy to implement via Spring AOP or AspectJ. You really do not need any ugly reflection. Just one more question before I show you how as the information is missing from your pseudo code: Do all methods called this way have `void` return type or can it happen that they return something else and that the result is somehow consumed by the caller? And are the methods static as your example suggests or non-static? I suggest you edit your sample code to be executable and really show what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This goes by reflection. As you will see by a terribly inefficient construct:

```
void execute(int needs) {
    for (Method method : Example.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        Execute annotation = method.getAnnotation(Execute.class);
        if (annotation != null && annotation.type() == LAYOUT
                && annotation.needs() == needs) {
            method.invoke(this);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Other designs would be thinkable, but I have to work too.

Comment: I thinked in this possibility, but I wanted use AOP, because I will need use this in many Java Class.

Comment: Better I think, would be an annotation processor that generates code, maybe with java SPI: you call execute against an interface and the generated code picks the right method. Annotations are totally static, so lends itself for code generation. AOP when already in use, is a hammer which turns everything into a nail. Not wrong too.